# Hover effect in nav bar doesn't work as wished

Tags: html, css

I created a hover effect for my navigation bar / the list inside it. On hover I want to create a "pressed button" effect by applying a box shadow. But the shadow only is casted in a small box. (check picture below)

[image: hover effect]

I want the shadow to fill out the whole navbar around the hovered area.
I have no idea where to put my code and would be glad about any help :)

HTML CODE:

```
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Projekte</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS CODE:

```
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
background-color:white;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.nav-wrapper {
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 50px;
width: 60%;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
color:#787878;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #BDBDBD;
border-radius: 5px;
background: #f9f9f9; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f9f9f9 0%, #ededed 100%); /* FF3.6+      */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f9f9f9), color-stop(100%,#ededed)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #f9f9f9 0%,#ededed 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #f9f9f9 0%,#ededed 100%); /* Opera   11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #f9f9f9 0%,#ededed 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #f9f9f9 0%,#ededed 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f9f9f9', endColorstr='#ededed',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

ul {
list-style: none;
}

li {
display: inline;
padding: 0 15px;
}

li:hover {
box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #BDBDBD inset;
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
color:#787878;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post an image to give us an idea of what you want to achieve? It can be also the same ibage with a colored border to show where you want to put the shadow.

Comment: @LuciaBentivoglio Yup.. See my answer comment, he has said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this:

```css
li:hover {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #BDBDBD inset, 2px 2px 3px #BDBDBD;
}
```

**Preview:**

[image]

---

Or the bevelled effect here:

```css
li:hover {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #BDBDBD inset, -2px -2px 3px #BDBDBD inset;
}
```

**Preview:**

[image]

#### Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/wolotuxico/1/edit?html,css,output

---

**Update from Comments**

Remove padding for `.nav-wrapper` and give it to `li`

```css
.nav-wrapper {
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

**Preview:**

[image]

#### Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/bowawodode/2/edit

Comment: sorry, I think I wasn't specific enough about my problem. I want the shadow to be casted around the whole navbar. I marked the area in this pic: http://i.imgur.com/GfYkS19.png

Comment: @Pixell Updated the answer. Kindly check!

Comment: Thanks you so much, that small change just made it perfect for me!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the padding from the navigation and add it to the li's. Remember the border is outside the padding and inside the margin.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/m98yedk6/1/

```
.nav-wrapper {
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 50px;
width: 60%;
color:#787878;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #BDBDBD;
border-radius: 5px;
background: #f9f9f9; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f9f9f9 0%, #ededed 100%); /* FF3.6+      */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f9f9f9), color-stop(100%,#ededed)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #f9f9f9 0%,#ededed 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #f9f9f9 0%,#ededed 100%); /* Opera   11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #f9f9f9 0%,#ededed 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #f9f9f9 0%,#ededed 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f9f9f9', endColorstr='#ededed',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
li {
display: inline-block;
padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: How is it different from my answer?

Comment: @PraveenKumar You hadn't edited your post before I posted this.

Comment: My post is 28 mins ago, and yours is 11 mins. `;)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Before you edited your answer was wrong.